# Define a function by looking at its graph

Tags: functions, graphing-functions

I have a set of ordered pairs of points from $\mathbb{R}^2$,and I need to define a function based on the graph of those points. The problem is that the function does not look like a usual function(i.e. a exponential or log function or the quadratic and so on). What options do I have?
Here is the points that I have:
 (1526, 6.40) 
 (1316, 8.80)
(2272, 16.0)
(1926, 15.6)
(2756, 31.4)

(2040, 21.8)
(3198, 38.4)
(5296, 87.0)
(3622, 65.0) 
(2512, 45.2)
(2958, 51.4)
(2126, 62.0).

Comment: Well, is there any reason to imagine this data should define a nice, sensible function?  I did a linear regression...it isn't terrible.  $y=.02x-15.216$ has $R^2\sim .72$.  I've seen worse.  What sort of function did you expect?

Comment: I don't expect any sort of function. I just wanted to express those data as a function for easier computation. Thank you!

Comment: So...is my regression line satisfactory?  I should say...in practice, one almost always has some preconception of what the data should look like.  A model for the situation, or some guiding principle or other.  As I expect you did, I tried a bunch of parametrized curves and nothing I did looked better than the regression line.  So...linear + normal noise would be my guess, absent any guidance from the context.

Comment: Your solution does have some error factor. For example f(3198) = 48.744 and as you can see from my set of points the result should be 38.4. Anyways your solution shoud be enough for what I want and if not I would try to approximate better using Taylor polynomials or another method. Anyways I will tell you more when I'll get home.

Comment: Just to be clear:  my "solution" is the linear regression line.  That is, I asked my computer to find the equation of the line which minimized the squared distance to your points.  The line vaguely resembles the data...that's it.  Still, $R^2\sim .72$ suggests that the line explains a lot of your data, but certainly not everything.